# How to insert varchar (date) to DateTime field in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to write an insert query to insert Date(string) to a DateTime field.

This is my table

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TSTKSInterfaceRun](
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   AttendanceDate [datetime] NULL,
   DateOfInterfaceRun [datetime] NULL,
   TotalRecords [decimal](4,2) NULL,
   Company [varchar](200) NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have tried using this query

```
Insert into [TSTKSInterfaceRun] (AttendanceDate,DateOfInterfaceRun,TotalRecords,Company) VALUES(CONVERT(Datetime, '2017-05-01 18:01:00', 120),CONVERT(Datetime, '2017-05-01 23:00:00', 120),1500,'SANCO')
```

but not working.
Error show as

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
```

in SSMS.
 I need a query to insert a string(date) to DateTime column in SQL table
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to check it first by changing the DataType of  "TotalRecords" column from [decimal](4,2) NULL to [decimal](6,2) NULL if you are inserting 1500 as a value in this column.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an *error*? If so, *what* error? Do you get some unexpected behaviour that isn't an error? If so, describe *what you were expecting* and *what happened*. We're not mind readers.

Comment: Thanks @AnkitkumarTandel. After chaning [decimal](4,2)  to [decimal](18,2) .. Insert query working fine

Comment: @Arun D Welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value 1500 is too large for a scale (4) and the precision(2). With (4,2) the max digits is 4 with 2 being decimal places. The maximum number that this field can hold is 99.99